# css style <button> shows grey background

Tags: css, button

I'm styling some  and my add to cart buttons look fine but I'm trying to create circular buttons for my wish lists and I'm still seeing grey behind them.  I'm thinking this might be the browsers' default styling taking over but I'm not sure, has anyone ever seen something like this?

The larger "add to cart" button looks perfect.  It's so weird, here's my code and a pic

```
.button {
    color: #fff;
    background: #a4cd45;
    border: 1px solid #8bb43f;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 135%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    transition: background 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1);
    border-radius: 4px
}
a.button:hover {
    background: #8B0204;
    border-color: #8B0204;
    color: white
}
.wishlist {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #a4cd45;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 17px 10px 0 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    font-size: 90%;
    cursor: pointer;
    float:right
}
```

[image]

Comment: If the <3 one is the issue, `border: none` will get rid of the grey surroundings.

Comment: Use the same border as the other (or remove it): http://jsfiddle.net/65TgF/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `.wishlist`

Insert:

```
border:0;
```

If you want it to disappear.

P.S: You had `border: 1px solid #8bb43f;` for the other button, which would also work fine for this!

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rnn8H/)

Answer (score 0):

Here I've made a Sample using `a` tag and as well using `button` element. Please have a look at the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/hoxodube/1/edit)**.

```
/*---------------Using Button Element-------------------*/

button.wishlist{
   background-color: #a4cd45;
   border-radius:50%;
   height: 40px;
   width: 40px;
   border:0;/*If remove this property you will see a gray background as shows on image*/
   color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
   display:block;
   margin: 17px 10px 0 0;
   position: relative;
   outline:0;
  cursor:pointer; /*Give an Effect of Clickable*/
}
button.wishlist:hover:before{ text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ef8913; }

button.wishlist:before {
    content: "\f08a";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    left: 10px;
}

/*---------------Using anchor Element-------------------*/

 a.wishlist{
   background-color: #a4cd45;
   border-radius:50%;
   height: 40px;
   width: 40px;
   border:0;
   color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
   display:block;
   margin: 17px 10px 0 0;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 2;
   font-size: 90%;
   cursor: pointer;
   float:right;
}
a.wishlist:hover:before{ text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ef8913;}

a.wishlist:before {
    content: "\f08a";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Is this answer helpful for you?